# How to resolve "Failed to load PDF document" in Moodle 2.9.2?

Tags: image, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.9.2 and I manage my website to local server. It works fine on webserver but in local I have problem in all data like images how show like this and pdf files "Failed to load PDF document".

[Moodle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmc3Y.jpg)

Comment: Your image appears to be corrupted, would you try uploading it again?

Comment: Downvoting, for non-reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the Moodle data directory too

Look for `$CFG->dataroot = 'xx'` in `config.php` on the web server, zip this up and copy to the data root directory on the local server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I copied moodeldata to local root server but my my problem existe

Comment: I download my website from server one more time but same result. Please any other solution??